# Why is the value of $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{1}{x^n}$ depend on $n$ being even or odd?

Tags: calculus, limits

I have the limit 
$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{1}{x^n}$$

Why, when $n$ is even this limit is infinity and when $n$ is odd this limit is indeterminate?

Answer (score 6):

In order for a limit to exist $$\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to a^-}f(x)$$
What does happen when $n$ is odd,are those equal?

Answer (score 2):

Recall that in order for $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ to exist we require that $\lim_{x\to a^-}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)$ exist. Consider the limit of $1/x^n$ as $x\to 0$ where $n$ is even. Since $n$ is even then $1/x^n$ will always be positive. Thus, we will have $\lim_{x\to0^-}1/x^n = \lim_{x\to0^+}1/x^n = \infty$ so $\lim_{x\to0}1/x^n=\infty$. Now consider the limit of $1/x^n$ as $x\to0$ when $n$ is odd. Since $n$ is odd then $1/x^n$ will be positive or negative depending on the sign of $x$. In particular, $1/x^n$ is negative for $x<0$ and positive for $x>0$. As a result, the limits from above and below will differ so the two-sided limit does not exist.